# Rent a racing bicycle in the Eifel, Germany

Tags: germany, bicycles, rental

Is it possible to rent a racing bicycle in the Eifel, Germany? I seem to find only mountainbikes when I search for 'fahrradverleih'. Anywhere near Stadtkyll would be awesome.

Comment: Do you mean an actual competitive racing bike, or simply a street bike built for speed on flat hard ground?

Comment: @ Djclayworth I'm not sure about the difference between those two, but I do not intend to part in a competition of some sort. But I do mean a lightweight bike with racing handlebars, clickable pedals and many gears.

Comment: The usual term in (N. American?) English that contrasts with 'mountain bike' is 'road bike'. A 'racing bike' is a more specific type of road bike.

Comment: Probably in America. In Europe we have ordinary bikes (with straight handlebars), mountainbikes and race bikes. The last one look the same as the bikes that are used by the pro's in the Tour the France, although those are probably much more expensive.

Comment: It's **Rennrad** in German. The configuration may vary so I'm pretty sure you have to call them on the phone.